# How to fix Windows system file digital signature that prevents booting

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, drivers, digital-signature

I was using my laptop in Windows on Macbook Pro this morning and decided I should reboot after a software update (non-Windows).

Assuming all was fine, Windows prompted me with the "Diagnosing your PC..." and then presented me with a failure to repair my PC.

I was confused because I was just in Windows and was doing a simple reboot.

After reading, I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/605158/how-to-get-out-of-automatic-repair-loop-in-windows-8) and tried the first option

```
Run this command on recovery prompt:

bcdboot c:\windows
```

After that, I rebooted and Windows presented me with an error that the file "vmsproxy.sys" wasn't digitally signed.

I went to F8 and disabled signing verification and Windows booted just fine.

After each reboot I'm presented with this error preventing me from booting and I have to disable signing verification.

I'm not sure what this vmsproxy.sys belongs to, some searching suggests my virtual machine switch, but I'm not positive.

I have no clue how to get the proper file back, I've even ran this command with no success to fix this file:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I could disable and re-enable Hyper-V and maybe it'll reinstall, but I haven't gone that far.

Answer (score 0):

If it is complaining just about this single file you could just grab a copy of the same file from healthy Windows installation.
Bare in mind that it should be same version and build of Windows. You can check that by running `ver` command from command prompt.
I am not sure which version of Windows you are running. I run Win 10 and have two versions of the file. One at this location
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-hyper-v-d..s-vmswitch-netsetup_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.103_none_be69061af918233b
and the other one here
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-hyper-v-d..s-vmswitch-netsetup_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_b1dc374771fef683

Hope this helps

Comment: I really don't know if that's the only file it's complaining about or the first file it checks and errors on.  I will try to find another build of Windows 10 that has this file and replace it and backup this other one first of course.

Comment: I updated my answer with locations. Also provide the Windows build. Maybe I could help

Comment: I could zip it and drop it somewhere

Comment: Replacing the file from those folders didn't work, Windows wouldn't boot saying there was an error with the .sys file.  I decided to try uninstalling Hyper-V and I was able to reboot fine without disabling driver signing.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, but why the downvote, please? I believe it was valid suggestion and effort and research was put in the answer. It's possible I dont understand downvote enough as i am new here. I though it was for like really stupid answers. Thanks and sorry if i am wrong

Comment: You are correct, it's for stupid answers.  I wasn't the one that downvoted.  Looks like someone just came through and did drive-by downvotes on my question, my answer and your answer.  I will offset the downvote to your answer if you offset my question and answer, deal?

Comment: Will do :). Just need 5 more reputation points to be able to upvote yours. should be soon. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I went to Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off and un-ticked Hyper-V and let it uninstall.  This allowed me to boot into Windows without disabling driver signing checks.

I have no need for Hyper-V at the moment, so I haven't re-installed, but I assume re-installing Hyper-V will properly setup and not have this issue again.